# Sending video stream from server to multi client using python

Tags: python

I want to create a video streaming server that can send the video to several clients. this image below explains what I want to achieve
[image]
please, is there anyone who can help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future please use SO to post code that doesn't work or is missing functionality instead of outright asking for a solution to a problem. Although I can't personally say I have experience with this kind of thing, you can probably just use a `<video></video` tag on every client, and use the `requests` library to get video from a server like YouTube and `django` to serve to client.

Comment: Are you doing any processing on the YouTube Video?

Comment: I do a treatment on a client that sends a video stream. the client can be a vlc or url = youtube.com